# JSplitPane in JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlayeredpane, jsplitpane

I want the right content of an JSplitPane to fill the entire available space and the left content (panel) to be on top of the other panel. I was thinking about using a JLayeredPane to solve that problem but I couldn't get it to work. 
My class currently looks like this:

```
public class LayeredPane extends JLayeredPane {

  private Component topComponent;

  private Component mainComponent;

  public LayeredPane() {

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  }
 public Component setTopComponent(Component c) {
    this.topComponent = c;
    if (topComponent != null) {
        topComponent.setVisible(true);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        setLayer(c, DEFAULT_LAYER + 1);
        add(topComponent, gbc);
    }
    return topComponent;
}

public Component setMainComponent(Component c) {
    this.mainComponent = c;
    if (mainComponent != null) {
         mainComponent.setVisible(true);
         GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
         gbc.gridx = 0;
         gbc.gridy = 0;
         gbc.weightx = 1;
         gbc.weighty = 1;
         gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
         add(mainComponent,gbc);
    }
    return mainComponent;
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. You want the left pane to be on top of another panel? So there are three panels? Could you add an image of what it should look like?

Comment: So a basic JSplitPane has two Panels in it. The left content-panel and the right content-panel. They are separated by an divider. By dragging the divider one can specify how much of the split pane's total area goes to each component. What I have in mind is that one component has the entire space. The other component is on top of it, and one can pull the divider to give the top-component more space. The dragging of the divider would enlarge the overlapp. I don't really know how to put that into a simple picture.

Comment: And it's not as simple as using `JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT` instead of `JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT`? I'm afraid I still don't quite follow, this is all I have to offer. Good luck, hope someone here will understand the question better than I do!

Comment: I've found that link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav. That is basically what I want but in swing.

Comment: Ah.. now I see! So basically, _like_ a JSplitPane with left and right components. Except that the pane on the left, when expanded, is drawn _over_ the contents of the pane on the right. Instead of resizing, being drawn over the other component.

Comment: Yes! That is excactly what i want!

Comment: what you are asking is from HTML5 and comes under animated nav, and here what you have asked help on JSplitter(which has nothing to do with that kind of thing), If you really want a answer on your desired one rather what you are asking here then you better come through a question of like that which also follows the **Asking Questions on Stackoverflow Parameter**.