# JSplitPane: Possible to have one side empty/transparent to see lower layer underneath?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My aim is to have a bottom layer which will be a large JPanel, and a layer above that which features only one half of a JSplitPane. The intent is that I am able to expand and contract the Split Pane while the Panel beneath doesn't get resized - only covered up.

In my research, the only similar thing I found was this question:

[JSplitPane in JLayeredPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163471/jsplitpane-in-jlayeredpane)

The poster's goal is the same as mine, but they never received an answer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Possible to have one side empty/transparent to see lower layer underneath?

If you want to see the background of a parent component, then you need to make the child component transparent.

So, in this case you need to make the split pane transparent. You also need add a transparent component to the split pane.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SplitPaneTransparent extends JPanel
{
    public SplitPaneTransparent()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        setBackground( Color.YELLOW );

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane.setOpaque( false );
        add( splitPane );

        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setBackground( Color.RED );

        splitPane.setLeftComponent( left );
        splitPane.setRightComponent( Box.createHorizontalStrut(0) );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SplitPane Transparent");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SplitPaneTransparent());
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```